# Load image from URL and clearing cache

Tags: android, image, url, caching

My image has the URL `~website/image.jpg` and when I upload a new image the new picture is located in `~website/image.jpg?` using `?` as a cache cleaner (I think).

If I load the URL `~website/image.jpg` in my app I get the old picture.

How can I get the new picture (as in chrome when using '?') when using:

```
img.setImageBitmap( getBitmapFromURL( url ) );
```

using method

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL( String src ) {
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy( policy );
        URL url = new URL( src );
        HttpURLConnection connection = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput( true );
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( input );
        return myBitmap;
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding some arbitrary value after "?" like xample.com/?v=23 and test

Comment: Yes this was the correct approach. If you look my answer there had to be a random int behind the ?, plus i needed to add `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( true );`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( true );` and setting

```
URL url = new URL( url + "?" + new Random().nextInt() );
```

Did the trick. Unless the int gets the same value 2 times in a row..